# How to create Rules in Scrapy Python?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am getting trouble while creating rule.
let suppose my starting url is   http://www.example.com/search?q=news

when I open this url in web browser i get following source code:

```
<html><head>...</head><body>
<ul id="results-list">
<li class="result clearfix news">
<div class="summary">
<h3><a href="/sports/hockey/struggling-canucks-rely-on-schneider-to-snag-win-against-sens/article2243069/">Struggling Canucks rely on Schneider to snag win against Sens</a></h3>
<p class="summary">Nov 21, 2011&ndash; Eleventh place Canucks rely on goalie Cory Schneider to improve record to 10-9-1
</p>
<p class="meta"><a href="/sports/hockey/struggling-canucks-rely-on-schneider-to-snag-win-against-sens/article2243069/">http://www.example.com/sports/hockey/struggling-canucks-rely-on-schneider-to-snag-win-against-sens/article2243069/</a>
</p>
</div>
</li>
<li class="result clearfix news">
<div class="summary">
<h3><a href="/news/world/celebrities-set-to-testify-at-uk-media-ethics-inquiry/article2242840/">Celebrities set to testify at U.K. media ethics inquiry</a></h3>
<p class="summary">Nov 20, 2011&ndash; Hugh Grant and J.K. Rowling given opportunity to strike back against tabloids’ invasion of privacy
</p>
<p class="meta"><a href="/news/world/celebrities-set-to-testify-at-uk-media-ethics-inquiry/article2242840/">http://www.example.com/news/world/celebrities-set-to-testify-at-uk-media-ethics-inquiry/article2242840/</a>
</p>
</div>
</li>
...
</ul><!-- end of ul#results-list -->

<ul class="paginator">
<li class="selected"><a href="http://www.example.com/search/?q=news&start=0">1</a></li>
<li ><a href="http://www.example.com/search/?q=news&start=10">2</a></li>
<li ><a href="http://www.example.com/search/?q=news&start=20">3</a></li>
...
<li class="jump last"><a href="http://www.example.com/search/?q=news&start=90">Last</a></li>
</ul><!-- end of ul.paginator -->
</body></html>
```

Now I want to extract data from links(this link is present in ul#results-list) http://www.example.com/sports/hockey/struggling-canucks-rely-on-schneider-to-snag-win-against-sens/article2243069/ and so on...

I have created spider for that as following:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from thirdapp.items import ThirdappItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.example.com/search?q=news',
        'http://www.example.com/search?q=movies',
        ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow('?q=news',), restrict_xpaths('ul[@class="paginator"]',)), callback='parse_item', allow=True),
        )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        #item = ThirdappItem()
        items = hxs.select('//h3')
        scraped_items = []
        for item in items:
            scraped_item = ThirdappItem()
            scraped_item["title"] = item.select('a/text()').extract()
            scraped_items.append(scraped_item)
        return items

spider = MySpider()
```

**So what would be the rules so that I will achieve the results that I am expecting?**

Answer (score 1):

first, what results are you expecting exactly?
second, maybe you should address the links in your rules, and not only the ul-container, which contains list item-nodes, which than has the required link-nodes!?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, SgmlLinkExtractor `allow` parameter - a single **regular expression** (or list of regular expressions) that the (**absolute**) urls must match in order to be extracted. So `allow` parameter would look like:

```
allow=('.*\?q=news.*',)
```

And most likely, the last parameter of Rule is not `allow`, but `follow=True`.

Final rule (note the escape character for the question mark):

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('.*\?q=news.*',), restrict_xpaths=('ul[@class="paginator"]',)), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
```